# Progress dialog is not showing while calling a web service

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to show progress dialog when user click on login button. I tried this but the dialog is not showing

```
btn_logIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         getUserCredentials();
     }
}); //end of anonymous class

private void showProgressDialog() {     
    if (dialog == null) {       
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);          
    }
    dialog.setMessage("Please Wait. Your authentication is in progress");
    dialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)              
            dialog.dismiss();               
        }           
    }); //end of anonymous class        
    dialog.show();  
} //end of showProgressDialog()

private void getUserCredentials() {

    EditText txt_userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_userName);
    String userName = txt_userName.getText().toString();

    EditText txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    String password = txt_password.getText().toString();

    if (userName != null && !userName.trim().equals("") && password != null && !password.trim().equals("")) {                   
        showProgressDialog();       
        callWebService(userName, password);         
    }
} //end of getUserCredentials()

private void callWebService(String userName, String password) {

    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("userName", userName);
        ....            
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();             
        if (result.equals("true")) {                
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {                
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                             
        }

     } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {            
         dialog.dismiss();
         Toast.makeText(this, "Service is not connected, Please make sure your server is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                       
    }  catch(Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to connect, please try again later. Thank you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
     }
} //end of callWebServide()
```

Am i doing anything wrong. When i click on login button and service is not running then it shows message that **Service is not connected, Please make sure your server is running"**, but the dialog isn't showing...Why? My logic is when user click on login button and fields have values then start showing progress dialog and if anything happens like when result come or server is not running or if any exception happen , then i remove the dialog and show the appropriate message, but dialog isn't showing...Why? What i am doing wrong? Please help..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Change your getUserCredentials() like this,

```
private void getUserCredentials() {

    EditText txt_userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_userName);
    String userName = txt_userName.getText().toString();

    EditText txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    String password = txt_password.getText().toString();

    if (userName != null && !userName.trim().equals("") && password != null && !password.trim().equals("")) {                   
        showProgressDialog();
 Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
             callWebService(userName, password);  

        }
    });   t.start();    
  }
}
```

And your **callWebService** method like this,

```
private void callWebService(String userName, String password) {

try {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("userName", userName);
    ....            
    Object result = envelope.getResponse();             
    if (result.equals("true")) {                
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {  
        ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
         dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

    }
});              

    }

 } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {  
      ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
          dialog.dismiss();
     Toast.makeText(this, "Service is not connected, Please make sure your server is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                       
    }
});           

}  catch(Exception e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();
 ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
           dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to connect, please try again later. Thank you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                       
    }
});   

 }
```

}

**Update 1**

To answer your questions from your comments,

1)Yes Async Task is more efficient. It has its own methods to do the same task what I have described here.

AsyncTask has the following methods,

**i)onPreExecute()-which can be used to start your Dialog
  ii)doInBackground()-which acts as the background thread. 
  iii)onPostExecute()-which gets called at the end where you can dismiss the dialog.**

The reason why I didn't mention is that, there are possibilities that you might have to change your working code's structure to adapt to Async task.

2)**runonUiThread**- as the name indicates, anything inside this will be considered as it is running in the main UI thread. So basically to update the screen you have to use this. There are also other methods available, like Handlers which can also do the same task.

Comment: Hi thanks. It is giving me error at line `public void run() { callWebServide(userName, password);}` that `Can not refer to a non final variable userName inside an inner class defined in a different method`. How can i remove this? Why i am getting this error ?

Comment: ok. Not a problem. Can you assign the Strings userName and password what you use to get the text from EditTexts as global variables on the top of your activity.

Comment: Yup if it makes no burden on my code(mean garbage collector) You mean as an instance variable ?

Comment: I think then i should also declare the result varibale as instance variable too `Object result`. Because we are also using it inside the inner class. Also you use in each condition `ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread{}` but not in the codition `if (result.equals("true")) {dialog.dismiss(); }`. Is there any special reason for it ?

Comment: Yes exactly. You have to declare that variable also as a Global. And once you finish with it, you can just null it. And sorry, I missed that part. You need to add runonUi there also

Comment: Cool :). Now time to ask some questions, please don't mind :). First Samir Mangroliya said that use Asynctask when i said that can i use thread here. Why? Is AsyncTask is more efficient? Second i know that you are calling web service in a separate thread by making thread class that is impelmenting Runnable intercface. What is the line `LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread()` is doing. It is also implementing runnable interface but what actually `runOnUiThread()` method is. Why we are using it here? I know its too much but can you please explain it to me? ...Thanks

Comment: hhmm thanks. For `runOnUI` you mean to say that we started the dialog in the UIThread. But we are closing it in a seperate thread. i.e. inside the `callWebService()` method. So we are basically saying here to our Activity which is `LoginActicity.this` that close the dialog that is running in your thread i.e. in UIThread . Am i right?

Comment: Hmm thank you so much for your help :). Although you told me that how can i use thread here but you also said that AsyncTask is more efficient so i will definitely try to adopt this in my code. Thanks to Samir Mangroliya also for posting such a nice example :). Thanks Andro:) you rock ;)

Comment: one thing more how can i stop the ruuning thread, because it is continue to run in the background? even my result has come or i move to another activity ?

Comment: HHmm you mean if i want to then i can use a boolean instance variable`(boolean isThreadRun; )` and when click on login button set it to true and then use `{while(isThreadRun){callWebService()}}`. And then in the runOnUI method set it to false after `dialod.dismiss()`. This will stop the thread to calling `callWebService()` again and again ... Otherwise no need to worry it will be stop automatically by the garbage collector... I think that's why AsyncTask is more efficient, because it handles all the work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask for it when ever task started at that time initialise your widget and then call your webservice from run method and close your progress bar on stop method.